# Unity - xcode 15 linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, xcode15

Using Unity 2022.3.12f1 initially to Xcode 15, but continue to get;

Unityframework 2 issues
Undefined symbols:
'linker command failed with exit code 1' errors causing the build to fail.

I can't seem to get any more data than this to go down the solution rabbit hole.

I tried

adding -ld64 “Other linker flags” fixed in in Xcode 15

then

adding -ld64 “Other linker flags” fixed in in Xcode 15 beta 2 (installed to check it out)

Tried converting the project to a workspace. No dice.

At a loss... any help would be appreciated.

r